# How to detect a value change on an <input> element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an input element with default value of '2':

```
<input type="text" class="chapter" value="2" />
```

Which displays as follows when using jQuery mobile:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c">
    <input type="text" class="chapter ui-input-text ui-body-c" value="2">
</div>
```

I want to do something every time the value is changed by the user, so I say:

```
$('.chapter').change(function(i, el) { alert("coding is epic"); });
```

However, as I change the value to '5' and click off the element, nothing happens.  Checking out the developer tools shows me that the value is still '2', even though '5' is displayed on the screen.

The wierd thing is that it does work on the following element:

```
<input id="UploadFile" type="file" name="datafile">
```

when called for using:

```
$('#UploadFile').change(function(e){ //aaaaargh! });
```

How can I do something when this value changes? Also, there are many elements on the page with `class="chapter"`, all of type `<input>`, and I have attempted using `$('.chapter').each().change(function(i, el) {`

Comment: I don't see any error with your code as it is, so perhaps it's something else on the page. Also, your usage of `.each` is incorrect.

Comment: In the console enter `$(".chapter").val()` and you'll see it has changed.  It doesn't change the value attribute, but that's not important.  Not sure why your alert wasn't triggered though, unless it's a delegation issue.  Is it in a `document.ready` handler?

Comment: your code most likely isn't located in a place where it will get executed after the input has been added to the document.

Comment: Yes the code is included in a document.ready handler.  I don't understand it either!  PS- I guessed usage of .each was incorrect!  What about librarian's answer below?

Comment: @PatrickKeane [this may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events)

Comment: document ready isn't always the way to fix it. It's actually recommended against when it comes to jQuery Mobile.

Comment: No, you don't need $.each at all, and the interval from librarian looks irrelevant to me. All you need is a change event, and the only reason it doesn't work is because the input you are interacting with doesn't exist when the event handler is attached.

Comment: dont use `.ready()` use jQM events http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: Aaaah Kevin! Your a genius! It's not working because the <input> is dynamically loaded on the page, and wasn't there when the document.load function was run.  I should change my .change function to .on('change', '.chapterPageFrom', function()

Answer (score 0):

Kevin B wrote a comment:

> the only reason it doesn't work is because the input you are
>   interacting with doesn't exist when the event handler is attached

Your a genius Kevin! It's not working because the `<input>` is dynamically loaded on the page, and wasn't there when the document.load function was run.

I should change

```
$('.chapter').change(function(i, el) { #### });
```

to

```
$('.container').on('change', '.chapterPageFrom', function() { #### });
```

EPIC!